# grpc client code in cpp/c++ with metadata x-api-key/x-goog-api-key not working, gives me Broken Pipe for speech API

Tags: c++, grpc, google-cloud-speech

This is my main code for grpc using c++ to interact with google cloud speech API, you can see that i am calling context.AddMetadata("x-api-key", "AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

and in the logs below i can see that while client is writing, we get a Broken Pipe error(which is socket being closed by the remote)

Please let me know is this the right way to do it

Also i have tried using this key as well
context.AddMetadata("x-goog-api-key", "AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

In the docs as per this link:
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys

it mentions this

============snippet start==============
Calling an API using an API key
Calling an API varies, depending on whether you call from a gRPC client or an HTTP client.

gRPC clients
If a method requires an API key, gRPC clients need to pass the key value as x-api-key metadata with their method call.

============snippet end============

which does not work? please explain why ?

Also, in the examples given, there is auth_token with authorization key provided in python example? is that required with x-api-key ?

=====================

The only way it works is un-commenting the following commented line and not creating with grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()

//auto creds = grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials();

this is while creating the channel. you need to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, which works good for one service account.

but my requirement is to have client use multiple services(with possible multiple service accounts).
so what is the recommended way for my requirement ?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Create a Speech Stub connected to the speech service.
  //auto creds = grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials();
  /*auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel("speech.googleapis.com", creds); */
  auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel("speech.googleapis.com", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());
  if (channel == nullptr)
   {
        std::cout << "could not allocate channel" <<std::endl;
        return -1;
  }
std::unique_ptr<Speech::Stub> speech(Speech::NewStub(channel));
  // Parse command line arguments.
  StreamingRecognizeRequest request;
  auto* streaming_config = request.mutable_streaming_config();
  char* file_path =
      ParseArguments(argc, argv, streaming_config->mutable_config());
  if (nullptr == file_path) {
    std::cerr << kUsage;
    return -1;
  }
  auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::time_t start_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(start);
  std::cout << "time start " << std::ctime(&start_time) << std::endl;

  // Begin a stream.
  grpc::ClientContext context;

  context.AddMetadata("x-api-key", "AIzaSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

  auto streamer = speech->StreamingRecognize(&context);
  // Write the first request, containing the config only.
  streaming_config->set_interim_results(true);
  streamer->Write(request);
  // The microphone thread writes the audio content.
  std::thread microphone_thread(&MicrophoneThreadMain, streamer.get(),
                                file_path);
  // Read responses.
  StreamingRecognizeResponse response;
  while (streamer->Read(&response)) {  // Returns false when no more to read.
    // Dump the transcript of all the results.
    for (int r = 0; r < response.results_size(); ++r) {
      const auto& result = response.results(r);
      std::cout << "Result stability: " << result.stability() << std::endl;
      for (int a = 0; a < result.alternatives_size(); ++a) {
        const auto& alternative = result.alternatives(a);
        std::cout << alternative.confidence() << "\t"
                  << alternative.transcript() << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
```

In the logs i can see that the hTTP header is sent:
I1127 16:06:19.028497113   30954 chttp2_transport.cc:1374]   HTTP:0:HDR:CLI: x-api-key: AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

but while socket writing i receive the Broken Pipe error:

D1127 16:06:19.060125242   30954 tcp_posix.cc:1077]          DATA: 69 64 65 6e 74 69 74 79 2c 67 7a 69 70 'identity,gzip'
I1127 16:06:19.060200892   30954 tcp_posix.cc:1111]          write: {"created":"@1574831179.060166760","description":"Broken pipe","errno":32,"fd":9,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":998,"grpc_status":14,"os_error":"Broken pipe","syscall":"sendmsg","target_address":"ipv4:216.58.199.74:443"}

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a combination that we need to create SSL connection for adding metadata x-goog-api-key="your API key"

while creating the channel in the beginning...do this instead of insecure channel creation........

```
auto creds = grpc::SslCredentials(grpc::SslCredentialsOptions());
auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel("speech.googleapis.com", creds);
```

It makes sense to have secured connection when we are sending security compromising API key which "Man-In-The_middle" can sniff this somehow!

I have opened a topic on google-speech discussion to get few more answers like whether we can send somewhat bigger encoded authorization data using JWT tokens.. I will update here if anything is useful.